# error when listview option is clicked

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

My activity has a listview which is populated with data from my parse.com database, and the list does get populated no problem. It displays a list of names. I want to store the name of the selected item from the list in a variable and pass to another activity. List gets populated but on selecting error crashes the app. Heres my activity `

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener;

public class ResterauntList extends ActionBarActivity {
    String mValue;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resteraunt_list);

        Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
        mValue = bdl.getString("Value");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resteraunt_list);

        populateList(mValue);
    }

    private void populateList(final String Value) {
        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Restraunt");
                query.whereEqualTo("Location", Value);
                return query;
            }
        };
        ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(
                this, factory);
        adapter.setTextKey("Name");
        adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {

            public void onLoading() {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ResterauntList.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle(Value + " Restraunts Search");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String name = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleRestraunt.class);
                i.putExtra("restName", name);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.resteraunt_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}`
```

My xml for this activity is given below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gastronomaapp.ResterauntList" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/restListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I seem to keep getting this error

```
08-31 03:00:42.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2003): Process: com.example.gastronomaapp, PID: 2003
08-31 03:00:42.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2003): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

Checked many solutions and tried almost everything i could find online. Absolutely no clue whats wrong. Would appreciate any help
EDIT - Did a stack trace,tells me the error is on this line. Kinda had that intuition

```
String name = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleRestraunt.class);
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace and find the line where the error occurs.

Comment: Made an edit with the line withe error lines. thanks

Comment: Please look more closely at the stack trace. The code you posted cannot possibly cause the error you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on following line

```
String name = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

You are using

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter
```

insead of

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
```

so you can not cast it into the string. Try using below code

```
ParseObject object= (ParseObject) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

And then check the attributes of **ParseObject**  what you need in putExtra

Comment: The error stoppped, but it prints something like com.parse.ParseObject@b2083830. Am i making error in my parse object handling?